# Apply Filters and removing duplicates in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have list of objects from which I wanted to take out the particular field but I also wanted to remove duplicates also. I have written some code snippet but I wanted to make it more concise. I have one restriction that my project uses ES5. So, please suggest accordingly.

```
var type = [];
obj.forEach(function(o) {
    if(o.type && o.type !== 'null')
        type.push(o.type);
});

return type.filter(function filterDuplicates(elem, pos) {
    return type.indexOf(elem) === pos;
});
```

please suggest a better way to doing this. Input obj would be something as follows:-

> [
>       {
>           'type': 'string'
>       },
>       {
>           'type': 'string'
>       },
>       {
>           'type': 'integer'
>       }
>       ]

Result should be ['string', 'integer']

Comment: Check if value already exists before pushing to array. Question shows a serious lack of research effort

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users?s=1|79.7976)

Comment: Additionally, if this is running in NodeJS per your title, why the es5 restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `type.indexOf` to avoid adding duplicates.  `indexOf` looks for a value and returns its index if found, else it returns -1.

```
var type = [];
obj.forEach(function(o) {
    if(o.type && o.type !== 'null' && type.indexOf(o.type) === -1)
        type.push(o.type);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little shorter (not by much), but only needs to use one method `reduce` instead of a combination of `forEach` and `filter`.

```js
var obj = [{ 'type': 'string' }, { 'type': 'string' }, { 'type': 'integer' }];

var result = obj.reduce(function(p, o) {
  if (!o || !o.type || p.indexOf(o.type) !== -1) return p;
  p.push(o.type)
  return p
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I often like to use object properties to remove duplicates, especially for long lists. If you have a short list, using indexOf is fine. However, if you have a long list, this become more efficient. Essentially, "types" below is just used to store the type names as properties. Setting it to true is just to give it a value. Doesn't matter what you assign to it - all you care about is the property names at the end.

```
var input = [ { 'type': 'string' }, { 'type': 'string' }, { 'type': 'integer' } ];
var types = {};
var result = [];

input.forEach(function (obj) {
    if (o.type) {
        types[o.type] = true;
    }
});
for (var t in types) {
    result.push(t);
}
```